# query to get basic stats across several tables crushes my SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to do a basic simple data health check across a bunch of table in my DB to present to my users, so I created this:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StagingProducts 
 WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0) AS NumProducts,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StagingCategories 
 WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0) AS NumCategories,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ManufacturerSalesReps 
 WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0) AS NumSalesReps,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders
 WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0) AS NumOrders,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM StagingCustomers 
 WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0) AS NumCustomers,
(SELECT COUNT(ItemID) As CategoryItemsCount FROM StagingCategoryItems
 WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0
   AND ItemID NOT IN (SELECT ItemID FROM StagingProducts WHERE
                      ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0)
) AS AbandonedCategoryItemsCount,
(SELECT COUNT(ChildItemID) As ChildCount FROM StagingChildItems
 WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0
   AND ChildItemID NOT IN (SELECT ItemID FROM StagingProducts WHERE
                           ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0)
) AS AbandonedChildCount,
(SELECT COUNT(RelatedItemID) As RelatedCount FROM StagingRelatedItems
 WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0
 AND RelatedItemID NOT IN (SELECT ItemID FROM StagingProducts WHERE
                           ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0)
) AS AbandonedRelatedCount,
(SELECT COUNT(TagID) As RelatedCount FROM StagingTags
 WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0
   AND ItemID NOT IN (SELECT ItemID FROM StagingProducts WHERE
                      ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0)
) AS AbandonedTagCount,
(SELECT COUNT(ItemID) As ModifierItemCount FROM StagingProductModifierLists
 WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0
 AND ItemID NOT IN (SELECT ItemID FROM StagingProducts WHERE
                    ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID)
) As AbandonedModifierItemCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT, CustomerNumber FROM StagingCustomers
    WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0
    GROUP BY CustomerNumber HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   ) AS DuplicateCustomerCount
) AS DuplicateCustomerCount,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT, ItemID FROM StagingProducts
    WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0
    GROUP BY ItemID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   ) AS DuplicateItemCount
) AS DuplicateItemCount
```

This can runs super fast sometimes but at other times is just hangs the server.  What is the best way for me to approach getting this data from across several tables into a single query?

Comment: Is it hanging busily executing because it gets a bad plan or hanging doing nothing e.g. because it is blocked by another waiting transaction and is waiting on a lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are touching so many tables in your database and any of these tables can be used while you are running your query, if it's not super important to get the absolute latest information from your tables, I would use

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WebManager_DataHealth] @ManufacturerID INT 
AS 
BEGIN
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SELECT .....
END
```

Comment: Just add that above all of my SQL?

Comment: nope, just above this stored procedure or if it's not a stored procedure then wrap it in a transaction and set it to READ UNCOMMITTED, this should only be used when you are querying for none mission critical info as is the case in the query you are presenting (because it's only for data health check)

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WebManager_DataHealth]
 @ManufacturerID INT
AS
BEGIN

Answer (score 0):

As a first step to identifying the problems, I suggest separating each sub-query and selecting the current date and time between them - like so:

```
select getdate()

SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumProducts FROM StagingProducts 
WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0

select getdate()

SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumCategories FROM StagingCategories 
WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0
```

...

This should enable you to identify which are the problematic queries. (It may conceivably reduce the problem, if this is being caused by too many simultaneous demands on the database's resources.)

As a second step I would consider refactoring the NOT IN sub-queries as NOT EXISTS sub-queries - like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(ItemID) As CategoryItemsCount FROM StagingCategoryItems sci
 WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0 AND NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT NULL FROM StagingProducts sp WHERE sp.ItemID = sci.ItemID and 
        ManufacturerID=@ManufacturerID AND IsDeleted=0)
```

Although I have found this type of refactoring to improve performance, I strongly recommend checking run times for both NOT EXISTS and NOT IN forms - circumstances may differ.

I also suggest checking the query plans of problematic (ie. long-running) queries, and checking whether the indexes on the relevant tables are being used appropriately, as well as whether new indexes could improve performance.